# Avoid file extension in Magnolia requests

Tags: java, magnolia

I'm currently stuck with the following problem. My pages can be accessed via www.example.com/products and www.example.com/products.html (besides *.html every file extension is possible, e.g. *.wtf, *.lol, ...).

How can I configure Magnolia CMS to only handle requests without any extensions (e.g. redirect www.example.com/products.lol to a 404-page)?
Is there a setting or (in the worst case) do I have to write an URI mapper by my own?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/MIME+type+mapping) from the Magnolia docu?